# Simple Pan and Zoom in d3 v7

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, panning

I need to pan and zoom in a simple d3 node graph with d3 version 7.

```
const svg = d3.select("#network_graph")
                    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);
```

There doesn't seem to be any documentation / tutorial on how to use d3.zoom with v7 and this functionality has significantly changed in v7. The two sources I can find refer to specific maps renderings, I just need to zoom into a simple div with viewbox.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple D3 V7 zoomable graph example:

```js
const data = {
  nodes: [
    {id: 1, x: 100, y: 50},
    {id: 2, x: 50, y: 100},
    {id: 3, x: 150, y: 100},
  ],
  links: [
    {source: 1, target: 2},
    {source: 1, target: 3},
  ]
};

const svg = d3.select('svg');
const g = svg.append('g');

const handleZoom = (e) => g.attr('transform', e.transform);

const zoom = d3.zoom().on('zoom', handleZoom);

d3.select('svg').call(zoom);

const links = data.links.map(l => {
  const source = data.nodes.find(n => n.id === l.source);
  const target = data.nodes.find(n => n.id === l.target);
  return {source, target};
});

console.log(links);

g.selectAll('line.link')
  .data(links, d => `${d.source.id}-${d.target.id}`)
  .enter()
  .append('line')
  .classed('link', true)
  .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)  
  .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)  
  .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)  
  .attr('y2', d => d.target.y)
  .style('stroke', 'black');
  
const nodes = g.selectAll('g.node')
  .data(data.nodes, d => d.id)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('node', true)
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
  
nodes.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 10)
  .style('fill', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="300" height="200" />
```

Comment: Doesn't really seem to center when zooming in on 1 node first and then zooming in on another.